# POST Request Body on a Qwik City API Endpoint

Tags: rest, http, post, qwik

If I have this POST request to an API:

```js
fetch('/api/url/etc', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: 'exampleUsername',
    password: 'examplePassword',
  }),
})
```

How do I access the request's body? Here is where I'm starting with the API endpoint:

```js
import type { RequestHandler } from '@builder.io/qwik-city'

export const onPost: RequestHandler = async () => {}
```

Not really sure where to go from here though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the request body through the first argument of the function.

```ts
export const onPost: RequestHandler = async (requestEvent) => {
  const jsonBody = await requestEvent.request.json()

  const textBody = await requestEvent.request.text()

  const readableStream = requestEvent.request.body
}
```